# THREE JS - Imported GLTF model looking Fuzzy

Tags: three.js

I imported a the duck model from here:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/examples/models/gltf/Duck

It looks great when I place it in my scene it, but when I did a `.clone()` on it, it got all fuzzy.

I tried various "deep cloning" routines and either got errors or it just didn't make a difference. (I left the cloning code in my fiddle, it's commented out, but you can see what I tried.)

Here's the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/gilomer88/w459L7kx/69/

(Attempts at deep-cloning are on lines 186-194)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the tutorial I was using made no mention of having to set the render's SIZE... once you do that, everything works out and looks the way it should.
Voila.